# Sql query to return comma separated Column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 'Result' has the following data:

```
ID   Plant   Animal  Human  Alien
1    1       0       1      0
```

Columns data type - bit.

Here is the output I am looking for:

Plant, Human

And here is what I tried:

```
Select Stuff(
    (
    Select ', ' + C.COLUMN_NAME
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C
    Where C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
        And C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
    Order By C.ORDINAL_POSITION
    For Xml Path('')
    ), 1, 2, '') As Columns
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES As T
    where TABLE_NAME = 'Result'
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about the ID column?

Comment: i dont want ID column in the output. Jus want Column names whose value is 1 in csv format.

Comment: maybe just use `CASE ... WHEN` and return some string that equals to column name?

Comment: @demo yes. this was my plan b.

Comment: @DevSa I got the  TLSQL part working as well. Fully  dynamic, see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/48225/9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description**

You can `UNPIVOT` your result table.
Then you could join the `UNPIVOTED`view with your query.

Additionally, using `TLQ`L you could generate the list of columns dynamically in the `unpivot` command.

---

**Unpivot**

```
create view pivoted_data as SELECT name, score
FROM new_table
UNPIVOT
(
    Score
    FOR name in (Plant, Animal, Human, Alien)
) AS SchoolUnpivot;
```

---

**Final Query with View**

```
Select Stuff(
    (
    Select ', ' + C.COLUMN_NAME
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C , pivoted_data pd
    Where C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
        And C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME 
        AND pd.score > 0 AND pd.name = C.COLUMN_NAME
    Order By C.ORDINAL_POSITION
    For Xml Path('')
    ), 1, 2, '') As Columns
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES As T
    where TABLE_NAME = 'new_table';
```

---

### Query without View

You could also do it in one shot:

```
Select Stuff(
    (
    Select ', ' + C.COLUMN_NAME
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C , 
    (SELECT name, score
    FROM new_table
    UNPIVOT
    (
        Score
        FOR name in (Plant, Animal, Human, Alien)
    ) as pd1 ) AS pd      
    Where C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
        And C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME 
        AND pd.score > 0 AND pd.name = C.COLUMN_NAME
    Order By C.ORDINAL_POSITION
    For Xml Path('')
    ), 1, 2, '') As Columns
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES As T
    where TABLE_NAME = 'new_table';
```

---

### Limiting Result table to row with ID = 1

Added `where id = 1`

```
Select Stuff(
    (
    Select ', ' + C.COLUMN_NAME
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C , 
    (SELECT name, score
    FROM (select * from new_table where id = 1) as new_table2
    UNPIVOT
    (
        Score
        FOR name in (Plant, Animal, Human, Alien)
    ) as pd1 ) AS pd      
    Where C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
        And C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME 
        AND pd.score > 0 AND pd.name = C.COLUMN_NAME
    Order By C.ORDINAL_POSITION
    For Xml Path('')
    ), 1, 2, '') As Columns
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES As T
    where TABLE_NAME = 'new_table';
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/96939/6

### TLSQL fully dynamic solution

```
declare @csvList NVARCHAR(1000)
set @csvList = (Select Stuff(
    (
    Select ', ' + C.COLUMN_NAME
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C
    Where C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
        And C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
    Order By C.ORDINAL_POSITION
    For Xml Path('')
    ), 1, 2, '') As Columns
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES As T
    where TABLE_NAME = 'new_table')

declare @sql NVARCHAR(1000)   
select @sql ='
Select Stuff(
    (
    Select '', '' + C.COLUMN_NAME
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C , 
    (SELECT name, score
    FROM (select * from new_table where id = 1) as new_table2
    UNPIVOT
    (
        Score
        FOR name in (' + @csvList + ')
    ) as pd1 ) AS pd      
    Where C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
        And C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME 
        AND pd.score > 0 AND pd.name = C.COLUMN_NAME
        AND C.COLUMN_NAME <> ''ID''
    Order By C.ORDINAL_POSITION
    For Xml Path('''')
    ), 1, 2, '''') As Columns
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES As T
    where TABLE_NAME = ''new_table'''

EXEC sp_executeSQL  @sql;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/48225/9

### TLSQL fully dynamic solution using concat_ws

Based on the answer given by: Gordon Linoff below, I added the CSV list to be generated dynamically using TLSQL.

```
declare @sql NVARCHAR(1000)   
declare @csvList NVARCHAR(1000)
select @csvList = (Select Stuff(
    (
    Select ', ' + '(case when NOT(' + C.COLUMN_NAME + ' =  0) then ''' + C.COLUMN_NAME + ''' end)' 
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C
    Where C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
        And C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME AND C.COLUMN_NAME<>'ID'
    Order By C.ORDINAL_POSITION
    For Xml Path('')
    ), 1, 2, '') As Columns
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES As T
    where TABLE_NAME = 'new_table')

set @sql ='select id, concat_ws('','', ' +  @csvList + ') from new_table'

EXEC sp_executeSQL  @sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this..!

```
select stuff (csv, 1, 1, '') csv from (
 select 
    case when plant  = 1 then ',Plant'  else '' end 
   + case when Animal = 1 then ',Animal'    else '' end 
   + case when Human  = 1 then ',Human' else '' end 
   + case when Alien  = 1 then ',Alien' else '' end 
 csv 
 from ( 
  values  (1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
 ) cn (ID, Plant, Animal, Human, Alien) 
) fin
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server now supports [`concat_ws()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), so the simplest solution is:

```
select id,
       concat_ws(',',
                 (case when plant = 1 then 'Plant' end),
                 (case when animal = 1 then 'Anmimal' end),
                 (case when Human = 1 then 'Human' end),
                 (case when alient = 1 then 'Alien' e
                )
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this, using [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
with 
result as (
    select 1 as ID, 1 as Plant, 0 as Animal, 1 as Human, 0 as Alien
    ),
result2 as (
    select ID,'Plant' as X1, Plant as X2
    from result
    union all 
    select ID,'Animal', Animal
    from result
    union all 
    select ID,'Human', Human
    from result
    union all 
    select ID,'Alien', Alien
    from result
)
select ID,STRING_AGG(X1,',') 
from result2 
where X2=1 
group by ID
```